# Replace the string "//" with "/// " using the shell

Tags: shell, doxygen, octave, replace

I am trying to generate documentation of the Octave API using doxygen. However, doxygen recognizes only comments after `///` to be documentation and the comment style in Octave is to use only `//`. I decided to run a shell command to change this and found this

```
sed -i 's/old-word/new-word/g' *.txt
```

from [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-replace-string-words-in-many-files/). When I test the command using

```
sed -i 's/////// /g' *.txt
```

or

```
sed -i 's/"//"/"/// "/g' *.txt
```

I get the error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unknown option to `s'
```

or

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unknown option to `s'
```

respectively. How do I correctly use `sed` to replace `//` with `///`?

Alternatively, is a simpler way, such as, for example, opening all the files simuntaniously in some IDE and refactoring.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
sed -i 's+//+///+g' *.txt
```

It is unlucky to use / as a delimiter if you need to substitute /// for // xD.

Answer (score -1):

Use `strrep()` (*string replace*).
I am assuming variable "s" contains your string containing "//". Add the following code in your script:

```
strrep (s,"//","///");
```

In this case `/` acts as escape sequence for `/` and `//` .

Comment: Please, what command is "strrep"? I can google out only the MATLAB version. Also "man strrep" cannot find any documentation. But the problem is solved however. Thank you for the effort!